# RewriteRule to redirect example.com/12345 to https://example.com/index.html?id=12345

Tags: ubuntu, url-rewriting, redirect

I am trying to create a way for users to type the url as example.com/12345 and rewrite it as https://www.example.com/index.html?id=12345.  The "id" parameter should be a minimum of 6 digits and should have no maximum.  I don't seem to be able to get the first RewriteRule to work correctly.  When a user keys the url like `www.example.com/12345`, it redirects to `https://www./12345`.

The second RewriteRule is redirecting all other traffic to https://www.example.com without issues.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]{6,})$ https://www.example.com/index.html?id=$1 
        [QSA,L,R=301,NE]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: then write maybe `RewriteRule ^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)$ https://www.example.com/index.html?id=$1      [QSA,L,R=301,NE]`

Comment: Andra, thank you for replying.  I tried your suggestion.  The URL ***`www.example.com/12345`*** still gets rewritten as ***`https://www./12345`***.

Comment: and without your `RewriteCond`s and the last rule? Especially, the last rule - why that?

Comment: The site running on this box requires SSL.  So, any attempt to access the site must be redirected to https.  These conditions and the last rule were created by the person who setup the server for me.
My understanding of the rewrite rules is a little limited.  As I understand it, if the criteria of the first rewrite rule aren't met, it redirects to https.  But it doesn't seem to be working.
Any help you could give me with the rewrite rules and conditions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Leave your first three `RewriteCond`, instead of your first `RewriteRule` write mine, delete your second `RewriteRule`.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, it should be like this...`RewriteEngine On` `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]` `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]` `RewriteRule ^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)$ https://example.com/index.html?id=$1 [QSA,L,R=301,NE]`

Comment: The above rules doesn't seem to be correct.  If I type `www.example.com`, it doesn't redirect to https.  Also, if I type `www.example.com/12345` now, it doesn't redirect.

Comment: place your first `RewriteRule` _before_ all `RewriteCond`, then three `RewriteCond` and the second `RewriteRule`